# Using this inside loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use `this` inside loop, without jQuery. For some reason, it doesn't work. Why?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://google.foo">Google</a>

<script>
    /*
    // Plain JS - Works
    function doSomething() {
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].href = links[i].href.replace('foo', 'bar');
        }
    }

    // jQuery - Works
    function doSomething() {
        $('a').each(function() {
            $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('foo', 'bar'));
        });
    }
    */

    // Plain JS - Doesn't work
    function doSomething() {
        var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            this[i].setAttribute('href', this[i].getAttribute('href').replace('foo', 'bar'));
        }
    }

    doSomething();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you expect `this` to be the same as `links`?

Comment: Why do you want to use `this` instead of just going for the working code? Because it's cool? Because you want to understand [how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)?

Comment: Please take a look at _any_ JS tutorial that covers `for` loops. The problem should be pretty obvious.

Comment: @avck No, `this` does not refer to a function at all

Comment: @Bergi "Why do you want to use..." - yes, because I wanted to understand it for the future. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `this` won't work. You are iterating over an array. So there is no context for `this` (*at least related to array you using*).

You should refer to the current array element. Which is  `links[i]`

```
links[i].setAttribute('href', links[i].g....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function in your console. You will see that it returns the window object. Then you can click the window object and examine all it's properties.

```
function doSomething() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
  console.log(this);
  return this;
}
```

`this` is an object passed to the function according to it's scope. So it is not equivalent to jQuery objects.

Comment: "*You will see that it returns the window object*" - no, the function definition doesn't say that at all. It always depends on how the function is called!